# Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D not firing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I assigned a projectile to my enemy that shoots at the player, and this projectile has a collider2d which I marked as a trigger. And it doesn't seem to recognize my player collider. The projectile just goes through my player.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2d (Collider2D other)
{
    Player _player = other.GetComponent<Player>();

    if (_player != null)
        _player.ChangeHealth(1);

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

My Player Components:

[image]

Comment: Try to write some debug message inside OnTriggerEnter2d (Collider2D other) to ensure this is never being triggered

Answer (score 1):

There is a small typo in your method name. The "d" in "2d" needs to be capitalized.

`onTriggerEnter2d` ---> `onTriggerEnter2D`

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    Player _player = other.GetComponent<Player>();

    if (_player != null)
        _player.ChangeHealth(1);

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I will make the assumption that your 'player' object does not have a `Rigidbody2D` attached to it.

I strongly suggest you read the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) on colliders and how they interact with each other but as a very brief summary; In order for collisions to occur between two objects, at least one of them **must** have a `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` attached to them.

Attach a `Rigidbody2D` component to your player (you may want to mark it as kinematic so collisions don't affect it's position/rotation etc.) and it should then work as you expect.

Comment: I already have a Rigidbody2D component attached to my player and it is marked as kinematic. I have added a screenshot of my player components in my question.

Comment: I see, can you confirm that you have put the `OnTriggerEnter2d` on a script that sits on the bullet `GameObject`? In future please try to give us as much information as you can so we do not need to ask for more.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code in OnTriggerEnter2D to this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    // In your scene you have just two objects, so not really required now
    // may be interesting for you when you have more objects there
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        //Here add .gameObject to refer the GameObject which contains the collider2D
        Player _player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();

        if (_player != null)
            _player.ChangeHealth(1);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Besides that. You have added an image of the components in the GameObject Player. Add the same for the Bullet, or at least check this two things:

- The bullet is also in position Z = 0
- The bullet has got a collider2D with the **isTrigger** feature as
  true (checked), to detect the player.